# ECS task change

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to check the last status of an ECS task, if it is STOPPED then it has to trigger lambda using cloudwatch event. I am getting below error message while validating the JSON event.
**Error message**:
Event pattern contains invalid element (can only be Strings enclosed in quotes, numbers, and the unquoted keywords true, false, and null)

```
    **Code**:
    {
  "source": [
    "aws.ecs"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "ECS Task State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "clusterArn": [
      "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:17025:cluster/ecs-w2"
    ],
    "lastStatus": [
      "STOPPED"
    ],
    "overrides": {
      "containerOverrides":
        {
          "environment": 
            {
              "name": ["job_grp_nm"],
              "value": ["QA_INTEGRATION"]
            },
            {
              "name": ["secrets_targetdb"],
              "value": ["7034908/Snowflake/facilitiesNDI/QA"]
            },
        "name": ["suite-dev"]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know what's wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **two things wrong**:

1. The values should be expressed as array of string, e.g. ["value"]
2. Your `environment` can be an array of objects.

So it should be:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ecs"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "ECS Task State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "clusterArn": [
      "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:17025:cluster/ecs-w2"
    ],
    "lastStatus": [
      "STOPPED"
    ],
    "overrides": {
      "containerOverrides":
        {
          "environment": 
            {
              "name": ["job_grp_nm"],
              "value": ["QA_INTEGRATION"]
            },
        "name": ["suite-dev"]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

The above should be accepted, but I **can't verify** if this will correctly match your event.

Comment: Thank you so much, Marcin. I have two environmental variables like this .{
  "source": [  "aws.ecs"],
  "detail-type": [ "ECS Task State Change"],
  "detail": {"clusterArn": [  "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:17025:cluster/ecs-w2"],"lastStatus": "STOPPED],"overrides": {"containerOverrides":{
          "environment": 
            {"name": ["job_grp_nm"],
              "value": ["QA_INTEGRATION"] },
   {
              "name": ["secrets_target"],
              "value": ["SnowflakeI/QA"]
            },
        "name": ["suite-dev"]
        }   } }}  . I am new to this. Please help

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question, Can you please check ?

Comment: @E.Manju I don't think you can use `environment` like that. It may be not possible to have this level of granularity in your rules. You probably have to just remove `environment` and filter later on whatever is your target later on.